# Cognitive Services - How to add multiple Faces from a Live Stream to Azure FaceList ? (Python)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api, facial-identification

**Problem Background:**

I have created an Azure FaceList and I am using my webcam to capture live feed and:

1. sending the stream to Azure **Face Detect**
2. getting Face Rectangle returned by **Face Detect**
3. using the returned Face rectangle to add **Face Detected from Live Video Stream** to my FaceList.

(I need to create Face List in order to solve the problem I explained in my other question which is [answered by Nicolas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65070145/7731287), which is what I am following)

**Problem Details:**

According to Azure FaceList documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/face/facelist/addfacefromstream ,if there are multiple faces in the image, we need to specify the target Face to add to Azure FaceList.

**The Problem is, What if we need to add all the detected faces (multiple faces) in Face List? Suppose there are 2 or more faces in a single frame of video, then how can I add those two Faces to Face List?**

I have tried adding the face rectangles returned from **Azure Face Detect** into a Python List and then iterating Over List indexes, so that each face Rectangle can be passed to Azure FaceList one-by-one. But no use.

Still getting the error:

```
There are more than one faces in the image
```

**My Code:**

```
face_list_id = "newtest-face-list"
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


count = 0


face_ids_live_Detected = []  #This list will store faceIds from detected faces
list_of_face_rectangles = []
face_rect_counter=0

while True:
        ret, frame = vid.read()
        check,buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()
        base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(buffer).decode()
        print(type(img))
        detected_faces = utils.detect_face_stream(endpoint=ENDPOINT, key=KEY, image=img,face_attributes=attributes,recognition_model='recognition_03')
        print('Image num {} face detected {}'.format(count, detected_faces))
        count += 1
        color = (255, 0, 0)
        thickness = 2

        for face in detected_faces:
        
            detected_face_id = face['faceId']
            face_ids_live_Detected.append(detected_face_id)
            

            detected_face_rectangle = face['faceRectangle']
            list_of_face_rectangles.append(detected_face_rectangle)
            print("detected rectangle =",detected_face_rectangle)

            face_rect_for_facelist = list_of_face_rectangles[face_rect_counter]
            face_rect_counter +=1

       frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, *utils.get_rectangle(face), color, thickness)
       cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

       for face_id_live in face_ids_live_Detected:
                        similar_faces = face_client.face.find_similar(face_id=face_id_live, face_list_id=face_list_id)                
                        if not similar_faces:
                                print('No similar faces found !')
                                print('Adding Unknown Face to FaceList...')
                                facelist_result = utils.facelist_add(endpoint=ENDPOINT, key=KEY, face_list_id=face_list_id,data=img,params=face_rect_for_facelist)
                                persisted_face_id = facelist_result['persistedFaceId']
                        else:
                                print('Similar Face Found!')
                                for similar_face in similar_faces:
                                        face_id_similar = similar_face.face_id
                                        print("Confidence: "+str(similar_face.confidence))
```

From my **utils** file, code for **function facelist_add** is as follows:

```
def facelist_add(endpoint, key, face_list_id, data=None, json=None, headers=None,params=None, targetFace=None):
    # pylint: disable=too-many-arguments
    """Universal interface for request."""
    method = 'POST'
    url = endpoint + '/face/v1.0/facelists/'+face_list_id+'/persistedfaces'

    # Make it possible to call only with short name (without BaseUrl).
    if not url.startswith('https://'):
        url = BaseUrl.get() + url

    params={}

    # Setup the headers with default Content-Type and Subscription Key.
    headers = headers or {}
    if 'Content-Type' not in headers:
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
    headers['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = key


    params['detectionModel']='detection_03'
    

    response = requests.request(
        method,
        url,
        params=params,
        data=data,
        json=json,
        headers=headers)

    if response.text:
         result = response.json()
    else:
         result = {}

    return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped and especially [Nicolas R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3136339/nicolas-r). I just found a mistake and corrected it. Now the program is working like Charm.

Actually, Azure 'Face Detect' returns face Rectangle in *top,left,width,height* sequence which I was feeding directly to the faceList's targetFace.

Now I just swapped the first two values of Face Rectangle and it becomes ***left,top,width,height*** which is what the documentation says, and it's working fine now.

**Solution:**

I have added a new function that takes the faceRectangle dictionary and swap first two values.

```
list_of_faceRect_valuesonly=[]

def face_rect_values(faceRect_dict):
        temp_list=[]
        for key,value in faceRect_dict.items():
                temp_list.append(value)
        temp_list[0], temp_list[1] = temp_list[1], temp_list[0]
        list_of_faceRect_valuesonly.append(temp_list)
```

In order to extract values from list, I did following:

```
face_rect_counter=0
face_rect_for_facelist = list_of_faceRect_valuesonly[face_rect_counter]
face_rect_counter +=1
```

**Request to facelist_add function:**

```
facelist_result = utils.facelist_add(endpoint=ENDPOINT, key=KEY, face_list_id=face_list_id,targetFace=face_rect_for_facelist,data=img)
```

I have also changed my **facelist_add** function a little bit:

```
def facelist_add(endpoint, key, face_list_id, targetFace=[],data=None ,jsondata=None, headers=None):
    # pylint: disable=too-many-arguments
    """Universal interface for request."""
    method = 'POST'
    url = endpoint + '/face/v1.0/facelists/'+face_list_id+'/persistedfaces'

    # Make it possible to call only with short name (without BaseUrl).
    if not url.startswith('https://'):
        url = BaseUrl.get() + url

    params={}
    

    # Setup the headers with default Content-Type and Subscription Key.
    headers = headers or {}
    if 'Content-Type' not in headers:
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
    headers['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = key

    list_of_targetfaces  =[]
    list_of_targetfaces.append(targetFace)


    params={'targetFace':json.dumps(targetFace)}
    params = {'targetFace': ','.join(map(str,targetFace))}

    print("Printing TargetFaces(facelist_add function) ...",params['targetFace'])
    

    params['detectionModel']='detection_03'


    url=url + "?"


    response = requests.post(url,params=params,data=data,headers=headers)
    


    print("Request URL: ", response.url)

    result = None

    # Prevent `response.json()` complains about empty response.
    if response.text:
        result = response.json()
    else:
        result = {}

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have several faces in a picture, you have to provide a 'targetFace' in your call to `AddFace`:

> A face rectangle to specify the target face to be added into the face
> list, in the format of "targetFace=left,top,width,height". E.g.
> "targetFace=10,10,100,100". If there is more than one face in the
> image, targetFace is required to specify which face to add. No
> targetFace means there is only one face detected in the entire image.

See API documentation for this method: https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395250

Comment: This is what I am doing here , sending each face rectangle in params, but it's not working:

print('No similar faces found !')
                                print('Adding Unknown Face to FaceList...')
                                facelist_result = utils.facelist_add(endpoint=ENDPOINT, key=KEY, face_list_id=face_list_id,data=img,params=face_rect_for_facelist)

Comment: On your « facelist_add » method I don’t see where you are mapping those rectangles in the call to the API

Comment: Face Rectangles are sent via params in facelist_add function. 
Look at image 1: https://imgur.com/a/LR4taQd
and then image 2:
https://imgur.com/kBW3LSB

Comment: Read again my comment: once in your facelist_add operation you are not using this « params » input in the call to the API

Comment: I am sendin req to API here:
response = requests.request(
        method,
        url,
        params=params,
        data=data,
        json=json,
        headers=headers)

Comment: Yes but a few lines before: ‘params={}’ . Does this clean what you have passed in params in the method’s input?

Comment: Hello Nicolas, I have figured that the problem is in API call. it's where I am sending params. Acc to Azure documentation I should send a list of faceRectangle in params. But unfortunately, I am unable to do that after a number of tries. 
my request URL is like this:
{Endpoint}/face/v1.0/facelists/sample_face_list/persistedfaces?overload=stream&targetFace=10&targetFace=51targetFace=124targetFace=248&detectionModel=detection_01

params is sending each targetFace value separately and not the whole list. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: You should populate params['targetFace'] with the values of left,top,width,height of the face you want to add. something like params['targetFace'] = 'widthValue,heightValue,LeftValue,TopValue' - coming from your Detect call

Comment: I have also removed that params={} line

Comment: I think you should have a look to how Query strings work. When you do the following:  "targetFace=10&targetFace=51targetFace=124targetFace=248", you are not passing the right thing

Comment: i am doing this:
params['targetFace']=targetFace(This is the list containing left,width,top,height of face)

but when I print the URL  it automatically extract the values from list and send each value separately with repeating targetFace= like I have written above.

Comment: "targetFace=10&targetFace=51targetFace=124targetFace=248"
this is automatically done when I made request using python requests module

Comment: Someone explained the problem I am facin here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851315/how-to-send-a-list-in-python-requests-get

but the solution didn't work for me